# Am I allowed to gift alcohol to an adult as a minor?

Tags: canada, ontario

I am thinking about gifting alcohol to my boss as a parting gift. Does any law in Canada prohibit me from doing so?

Comment: How would you buy it to begin with?

Comment: They deleted answer is right tbh. You can not buy the alcohol so you can not technically gift it.

Comment: The deleted answer is obviously unjustified if not entirely wrong. There are ways for a minor to legally obtain alcohol, most notably being provided by a parent, so an answer saying "no" must show that any such alcohol cannot be given **from** the minor to someone else.